# Iteratively extracting fixed effects coefficients from a lmer model for use in bootstrap estimation

Tags: r

The following bit of code was developed in order to generate a c.i. for the location of a peak in a modeled relationship. A simple polynomial approach is used where the RD term and its interactions determines that location (the 'zeros' of the first derivative are what is being solved here: peak.temp=-(m1.coef[10]*0.16+m1.coef[9]*0.19)/(2*m1.coef[8]), from line 19 below).

The code was initially developed for use with nlme/lme and it works fine in that setting. The issue I'm having is related to transitioning for use with lme4/lmer models, which are better suited to dealing with the random effects.

The first error being thrown is: 'Error in m1.new$coefficients : $ operator not defined for this S4 class', corresponding to line=17 below. Searching on that error I (believe I) was able to determine that the syntax needs to be updated to work with the S4 class, and that appears to involve, at least in part, substituting a @ for the $. However, simply making that change, e.g. m1.new@coefficients@fixed leads to another error, which is what has me stumped. That message is: Error: no slot of name "coefficients" for this object of class "lmerModLmerTest"

While I was able to get the available slot names for the model (m1), I'm not clear on which, if any of these, are what I should be substituting for the previous 'coefficients' and possibly also 'fixed' terms in that line of code.

m1 slots are: "vcov_varpar", "Jac_list","vcov_beta","sigma","resp","Gp","call","frame","flist","cnms""lower","theta","beta","u","devcomp","pp","optinfo"

I suspect the source of this issue will be obvious to someone having experience with both packages nlme/lme4, and hope I have provided enough background to lead to a solution. Thanks much in advance!

#----------------------------------------------

```
### bootstrap for m1 ###
nreps=1000
df.rows=dim(data)[1]
peak.m1=numeric(nreps)
for (i in 1:nreps){
  # resample the rows of the data frame
  new.rows=sample(1:df.rows,df.rows,replace=T)
  new.df=data[new.rows,]
  # fit the model
  m1.new=lmer(gPAI.on ~ WAM.sc + H + EH.sc + skew.sc + QMD.R.14.sc + RD + I(RD^2) +
               EH.sc*RD + skew.sc*RD + skew.sc*EH.sc +
               (1|mu/plot) + (1|site.yr),
             weights=plot.wt,
             control = lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"),
             REML=F, data = new.df)
  # extract the fixed coefficients
m1.coef=m1.new$coefficients$fixed
  # compute the peak
  peak.temp=-(m1.coef[10]*0.16+m1.coef[9]*0.19)/(2*m1.coef[8])
  #save the peak
  peak.m1[i]=peak.temp
}
plot(density(peak.m1))
# find the mean and se for the m1 peak
(mean.sd=c(mean(peak.m1),sd(peak.m1)))
# a 95% confidence interval (assuming normality)
c(mean.sd[1]-2*mean.sd[2],mean.sd[1]+2*mean.sd[2])
# an empirical CI
quantile(peak.m1,c(0.025,0.975))
# check the normality of the peak estimates
shapiro.test(peak.m1)
```

Comment: Have you tried `fixef(m1.new)`? You shouldn't need to think about object internals or use `@`, because `lme4` implements extraction methods for you. See `methods(class="merMod")` and `?\`merMod-class\``.

Comment: Followed your suggestion and the script now runs. Thank you!